# shuttstock api image search in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, curl, httprequest

https://developers.shutterstock.com/guides/search
This is the api docs for shutterstock.

I am doing a simple image search using the shutterstock image seach api get request.

I am able to output a JSON file using curl(as shown in the api docs),

But If i do a http request through swift(in code),

I get an error.

This is my code for the http request

```
func set_image(country:String) {
    let client_id = "6e1f7771194a5a260e05"
    let client_secret = "secretttt"
    let base_url = "https://\(client_id):\(client_secret)@api.shutterstock.com/v2/images/search?query=\(country)"
    let escapedStringURL:String = base_url.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")
    let url = URL(string: escapedStringURL)
    print(url)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        if(error != nil){
            print("error in image search")
        }else{
            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]


                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
//                        self.trip_tableview.reloadData()
                    print(json)
                })

            }catch let error as NSError{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }).resume()

}
```

Is this because curl behaves differently?

If so, how do I run the http request using curl in swift?

EDIT

It's technically not an error I guess.

When I run my code it outputs (which is the same output I get when I just run the url in my browser),

{"message":"Authorization header required"}

But if i run the same url with curl I get the output that I want.

Comment: Could you at least output the error you're getting?

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my question

Comment: Have you found any way to do this? @DavidJuYoungKim